# How to improve time complexity in this code?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, time-complexity

What my code try to do here is to sort items trough 2 dictionaries.
If they are similar or the same, I create a new list to append them.

The test file is relatively big, around 2000 data each dictionary.

My concern is that i need to maintain a linear time complexity trough out the code and i am not sure that my code is on a linear complexity.

So i would like an opinion on the complexity of this code. Is it linear?
If it is not is there any way to improve it ?

Thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
import string
import textdistance as td
import time
start_time = time.time()


amazon =  pd.read_csv('amazon.csv')
google = pd.read_csv('google.csv')

title1 = amazon['title']
title2 = google['name']
id1 = amazon['idAmazon']
id2 = google['id']

out_amazon = {}
out_google = {}

list_a =[]
list_b =[]
list_c =[]
list_d =[]
list_e =[]
list_f =[]
list_g =[]
list_h =[]
list_i =[]
list_j =[]
list_k =[]
list_l =[]
list_m =[]
list_n =[]
list_o =[]
list_p =[]
list_q =[]
list_r =[]
list_s =[]
list_t =[]
list_u =[]
list_v =[]
list_w =[]
list_x =[]
list_y =[]
list_z =[]
list_unknown = []
duplicate_list = []

amazon_labeled = ([(name, 'Amazon') for name in title1])
google_labeled = ([(name, 'Google') for name in title2])

amazon_dict = dict(zip(amazon.idAmazon, amazon_labeled))
google_dict = dict(zip(google.id, google_labeled))

z = {**amazon_dict, **google_dict}
keys = sorted((z.values()))

i = 0
while i < (len(keys)) - 1:
    if (keys[i][0][0]) == 'a':
        list_a.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'b':
        list_b.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'c':
        list_c.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'd':
        list_d.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'e':
        list_e.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'f':
        list_f.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'g':
        list_g.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'h':
        list_h.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'i':
        list_i.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'j':
        list_j.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'k':
        list_k.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'l':
        list_l.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'm':
        list_m.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'n':
        list_n.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'o':
        list_o.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'p':
        list_p.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'q':
        list_q.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'r':
        list_r.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 's':
        list_s.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 't':
        list_t.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'u':
        list_u.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'v':
        list_v.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'w':
        list_w.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'x':
        list_x.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'y':
        list_y.append(keys[i])
    elif (keys[i][0][0]) == 'z':
        list_z.append(keys[i])
    else:
        list_unknown.append(keys[i])
    i += 1

def check_based_alphabet(alphabetList, k = 0, j = 0):
    while k < len(alphabetList) - 1:
        if alphabetList[k][1] != alphabetList[j][1]:
            distance = td.jaccard(alphabetList[k][0], alphabetList[j][0])
            if distance > 0.7:
                duplicate_list.append([alphabetList[k][0], alphabetList[j][0]])
            j += 1
        else:
            j += 1
        if j == len(alphabetList):
            j = 1
            k += 1            

check_based_alphabet(list_a)
check_based_alphabet(list_b)
check_based_alphabet(list_c)
check_based_alphabet(list_d)
check_based_alphabet(list_e)
check_based_alphabet(list_f)
check_based_alphabet(list_g)
check_based_alphabet(list_h)
check_based_alphabet(list_i)
check_based_alphabet(list_j)
check_based_alphabet(list_k)
check_based_alphabet(list_l)
check_based_alphabet(list_m)
check_based_alphabet(list_n)
check_based_alphabet(list_o)
check_based_alphabet(list_p)
check_based_alphabet(list_q)
check_based_alphabet(list_r)
check_based_alphabet(list_s)
check_based_alphabet(list_t)
check_based_alphabet(list_u)
check_based_alphabet(list_v)
check_based_alphabet(list_w)
check_based_alphabet(list_x)
check_based_alphabet(list_y)
check_based_alphabet(list_z)
```

Comment: Why didn't you use a 'dict' instead of making a list for each character in the alphabet!

Comment: FYI for working code that you want to optimize, this site is a better place: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: whats the goal youre trying to accomplish with amazon and google csv?

Comment: @bhristov Python doesn't have `switch`.

Comment: You should use a `for` loop instead of `while` to loop over list elements.

Comment: @AminGuermazi I will definitely try this 
however, does anyone know the time complexity of my code?

Comment: @Barmar usually for loop compare to while loop is much more complex. But do you think in this case, a for loop is better ?

Comment: @jss367 Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: If you do `for key in keys:` you can just refer to `key` instead of `keys[i]`. That makes the code simpler, especially when you have multiple indexes. `keys[i][0][0]` becomes `key[0][0]`.

Comment: It looks like your code is `O(n * complexity of td.jaccard)`. There doesn't seem to be anything in your code that's non-linear. It's just very repetitive and can be improved in many ways.

Comment: @Barmar Seems O(n^2 * td.jaccard) to me: the list of keys is split into 26 sublists, then for each sublist, each element is compared to every element of the same sublist (`k += 1` only when `j` reaches the end of the sublist). That's roughly 26 * (n/26)^2 comparisons. @Bobby: try to improve the code, usings dicts, for loops, etc. and the complexity will be easy to determine.

Comment: @jferard I think you're right. I only saw one `while` loop, didn't realize it was looping over both `j` and `k` and forming a cross product.

Answer (score 1):

You ask specifically for time complexity, but finding the time complexity is easier when the code is clean. So I will: 1. clean the code; 2. find the time complexity and discuss of the possible improvement.

## Clean the code

First, instead of creating `list_a`, `list_b`, ..., create a dict `list_by_first_letter`. We don't need to worry about indices:

```
for k in keys:
    letter = k[0][0]
    if not('a' <= letter <= 'z'):
        letter = 'UNK'
    list_by_first_letter.setdefault(letter, []).append(k)
```

The `setdefault` will check if the `letter` is already a key in the dict, and else create it and map it to a default value (empty list `[]` here).

And then, to find the duplicates:

```
for alphabet_list in list_by_first_letter.values():
    check_based_alphabet(alphabet_list)
```

Now, we have to clean `check_based_alphabet`. I replace `while` by `for`. Since you're matching every element against all the others you have:

```
def check_based_alphabet(alphabet_list):
    for k in range(len(alphabet_list)):
        first_key = alphabet_list[k]
        for j in range(len(alphabet_list))):
            second_key = alphabet_list[j]
            if first_key[1] != second_key[1]:
                distance = td.jaccard(first_key[0], second_key[0])
                if distance > 0.7:
                    duplicate_list.append([first_key[0], second_key[0]])
```

You may have an issue here: you compare `alphabet_list[0]` to `alphabet_list[1], alphabet_list[2], ...`, then `alphabet_list[1]` to `alphabet_list[0], alphabet_list[2], ...`. If your `td.jaccard` is symmetric, you'll get every couple twice. To avoid this, use:

```
...
for j in range(k+1, len(alphabet_list))):
...
```

You get rid of the duplicates since `second_key` is always *after* `first_key` in the list. (I won't claim that the code is now totally clean, but it is at least readable.)

## Time complexity

Now, we can find the time complexity. First, the time complexity of `check_based_alphabet` is `O(n^2 * complexity of td.jaccard)` where `n` is the number of element in the sublist. That's obvious because of the two imbricated loops.

If `N` is the number of elements in the list, you have a global time complexity of `O(n1^2 * complexity of td.jaccard) + O(n2^2 * complexity of td.jaccard) + ...` where `N = n1 + n2 + ...`, that is `O(N^2 * complexity of td.jaccard)`:

1. In the worst case, we have `N  = n1` and `n2 = ... = 0` and the result is trivial.
2. In the best case, we have `n1 = n2 = ...` and we have `27 * O((N/27)^2 * complexity of td.jaccard)` and that's still `O(N^2 * complexity of td.jaccard)`, while this may be faster.

It seems hard to improve that time complexity. Look at your trial: you group the keys in buckets (all keys that somewhat start with the same letter) and compare each key with all keys of the same bucket. Good idea, but the flaw is that the size of the buckets still depends on `N`. To reduce the time complexity, you have to create buckets of a fixed size. That's not possible unless `td.jaccard` and/or the keys have specific properties.

*(An example of specific properties: imagine you have a list of distinct integers, and that two integers `i, j` are said to be "duplicates" if `|i -j| < K` where `K` is independant of `N`. You can compare all pairs of integers (`O(N^2)`), but you can also sort the integers (`O(N lg N)` in the generic case) and then compare each element of the sorted list to the `K` next integers (above that, all integers are at least `i + K`, hence not duplicates): `O(N * K)`. Hence, the time complexity is `O(N (K + lg N))` better than `O(N^2)`.)*